# How to create a 5bit datatype in matlab?

Tags: matlab, custom-data-type

I have a matrix that every cell is exactly 5 bits and i need to store them in 5 bits (instead of 8 bit in uint8 for example) to reduce size of the matrix so i think i need to create a custom datatype .
Is there any sample code that show me how to create a 5 bits datatype with Matlab ?

Comment: No. There is no 5-bit datatype in any programming language (or processor, for that matter) that I know. The closest I think you are going to get is to concatenate three 5-bit elements into a 16-bit integer.

Comment: thank you but with your solution i will waste 1 bit in every 16 bits.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to make the conversion easier, but if you insist, you can concatenate 8 elements into 5 bytes. But I think if you're worrying about 1 bit out of 16 being wasted, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: I guess waisting time doesn't matter... whatever arithmetc you plan to do with your 5bpp matrix.

Comment: Using 40 bytes not to waste the single byte will end up in much slower code. With 16 bytes holding three variables you can directly use a uint16 and `bitget`. All PCs work with 1 byte = 8 bit units based addresses, using anything which is not a multiple of 8 bits typically ends up in a mess. That's why boolean typically use a full byte.

Comment: If you're still looking for options, maybe you can tell us what you're trying to do with this matrix and why you need to reduce the size.